# Time slot availablity in python

Tags: python

I am writing a slot booking algorithm for my application in python 
like this

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

appointments = [(datetime(2012, 5, 22, 10), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 10, 30)),
                (datetime(2012, 5, 22, 12), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 13)),
                (datetime(2012, 5, 22, 15, 30), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 17, 10))]

hours = (datetime(2012, 5, 22, 9), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 18))

def get_slots(hours, appointments, duration=timedelta(hours=1)):
    slots = sorted([(hours[0], hours[0])] + appointments + [(hours[1], hours[1])])
    for start, end in ((slots[i][1], slots[i+1][0]) for i in range(len(slots)-1)):
        assert start <= end, "Cannot attend all appointments"
        while start + duration <= end:
            print "{:%H:%M} - {:%H:%M}".format(start, start + duration)
            start += duration
```

This works fine for me if i am checking slot for a particular date within 9 hours to 18 hours 
But it is not fulfilling my requirements for week or month availability .Because i want to check availability for week or month between 9 hour to 18 hour .

Please help me to improve my code so that it could check the available slots between 9 hours to 18 hours for weeks and months also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend that `hours` applies to every day of the week or month (except perhaps some days off?), so you might change it to use `time` objects. Then for each day, you can `datetime.combine` to create an interval from the previous day's end until this day's start. Don't forget to create one more interval that starts at the last day's end.